# Multi-Device Hybrid App build error

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying the new multi-device hybrid app for vs2013 and I keep getting this error for every platform:
"The command ""C:\Users\Sahar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\vs-cli" build --platform "Windows Phone" --configuration "Debug" --projectDir . --projectName "TestApps" --language "en-US" --buildServerUrl "" --buildTarget "PhoneDevice"" exited with code 1.  C:\Users\Sahar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets    99  5   TestApps"

If someone could help me to understand this error and how to fix it, it would be great! Thanks in advance!